# Pause Google Analytics experiment

Tags: google-analytics

I recall that I could pause an experiment on Google Website Optimizer, but now that experiments have been moved over to Google Analytics, I don't see a way to do that (and knowing Google, there's a good chance that they just dropped that feature). Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this (short of changing the code on my site)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the feature isn't available in Google Analytics at this stage - one of the few places it is noted is in [this blog post](http://blog.convert.com/dirty-details-on-google-website-optimizers-new-big-brother.html):

> ... details that are currently not supported include copy a test and pause
>   a test. Users only have the option to stop a test but, because this is
>   a big problem for all users, I expect a quick fix after August 1.
>   These exclusions could not have been a technical limitation but most
>   likely were features that did not make the August 1 launch.

So hopefully it is coming soon. In the meantime you can stop the experiment, there doesn't seem to be any other work around.